Manjaro fails to open GUI of software manager (pamac-manager)
Since at least yesterday, my Manjaro (kernel 6.1.112-1) fails to open the GUI of the software manager. It is however able to open it in other instances: when the little icon reminds me, that there are updates to be made, it opens the software manager GUI in the update tab and I can run updates, but it crashes when I try to switch to another tab. When there are no updates to be made, I cant open it by any of the usual mouse clicks - instead I just get a message "software adding/deleting is started (failed)" (roughly translated from my system language). However I am able to open it via terminal by pamac-manager %U and if opened this way I can freely switch tabs (I havent yet tried opening it this way, updating something and checking whether it still works, just because right now there are no updates to be made). sudo pacman -Syu reveals everything is up to date (since a google search revealed that was the problem for someone else).
Maybe one of you can help me with where to look for the problem or what else to check or try out. I am thankful for any ideas.

I found an old answer that seemed to have been related to a specific update a year ago, but I tried it anyways and it worked. It was discussed here https://forum.manjaro.org/t/cant-install-update-any-applications-using-add-remove-software/147095
(I tried a few things before asking the question and forgot that I had one more tab open that looked feasible from its title and just saw it after I had posted the question. Tried it directly after and it worked... not sure if my timing, my awarenes or my patience is the problem here ^^)
Basically I just ran sudo pacman-mirrors -f && sudo pacman -Syyu , my system updated the mirror list and then reported there was still nothing to update. But the package manager GUI starts for now. So my best guess it was an issue with the mirror list, which may be checked when the package manager GUI is opened?
Anyways, I think I leave the question open for now, cause maybe someone else has a better answer or explanation than I do, but it seems to work for now in case anyone else runs into the same problem.
